# Symfony2 - Install TwitterOAuth library

Tags: symfony, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to install [Abraham's twitteroauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) without using FOSTwitterBundle. I want to use the API directly through the library.

My problem is that the library has no namespace assigned.
I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2) and arrived to this configuration:

```
# app/autoload.php
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    // ...
    'TwitterOAuth_'    => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twitteroauth/lib',
));


# vendor/twitteroauth/lib/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth_TwitterOAuth.php
require_once __DIR__.'/src/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
class TwitterOAuth_TwitterOAuth extends TwitterOAuth
{
}
```

In my controller:

```
$api = new \TwitterOAuth_TwitterOAuth('asd','asd');
```

And I still get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TwitterOAuth_TwitterOAuth' not found.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your path to the lib is wrong.

According to the link you gave, Geshi is :

```
# vendor/geshi/lib/Geshi/Geshi.php
```

For:

```
$geshi = new \Geshi_Geshi ();
```

So you should use:

```
vendor/twitteroauth/lib/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth.php
```

instead of

```
vendor/twitteroauth/lib/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth_TwitterOAuth.php
```

Comment: YES! That was my problem, I didn't see that, I was really silly. Thank you very much :)